# MS Access - Enforce Referential Integrity - Multiple Table Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: ms-access, referential-integrity

I have created four tables in MS Access to describe allowable configurations of personal fire fighting equipment for use as part of an asset register. The details follow:

```
TBL_1   :  FIRE_CLASSIFICATION
FIELDS  :   | PK | CLASS              |
---------------------------------------
ENTRIES :   | 1  | Fire Blanket       |
            | 2  | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 3  | Fire Hose Reel     |

TBL_2   :  FIRE_TYPE
FIELDS  :   | PK | TYPE               | FK_CLASS           |
------------------------------------------------------------
ENTRIES :   | 1  | General            | Fire Blanket       |
            | 2  | Carbon Dioxide     | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 3  | Foam               | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 4  | Powder ABE         | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 5  | Powder BE          | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 6  | Vap. Liquid        | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 7  | Water              | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 8  | Wet Chemical       | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 9  | General            | Fire Hose Reel     |

TBL_3   :  FIRE_SPECIFIC
FIELDS  :   | PK | SPECIFIC           | FK_CLASS           |
------------------------------------------------------------
ENTRIES :   | 1  | Dimensions         | Fire Blanket       |
            | 2  | Capacity (kg)      | Fire Extinguisher  |
            | 3  | Length (m)         | Fire Hose Reel     |

TBL_4   :  FIRE_OPTIONS
FIELDS  :   | PK | FK_CLASS           | FK_TYPE        | FK_SPECIFIC    | OPTION |    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENTRIES :   | 1  | Fire Extinguisher  | Carbon Dioxide | Capacity (kg)  | 2.0    |
            | 2  | Fire Extinguisher  | Carbon Dioxide | Capacity (kg)  | 3.5    |
            | 3  | Fire Extinguisher  | Carbon Dioxide | Capacity (kg)  | 5.0    |
            | 4  | Fire Extinguisher  | Powder ABE     | Capacity (kg)  | 1.1    |
            | 5  | Fire Extinguisher  | Powder ABE     | Capacity (kg)  | 2.1    |
            | 6  | Fire Extinguisher  | Powder ABE     | Capacity (kg)  | 2.3    |
            | 7  | Fire Extinguisher  | Powder ABE     | Capacity (kg)  | 2.7    |
            | 8  | Fire Extinguisher  | Powder ABE     | Capacity (kg)  | 4.5    |
            | 9  | Fire Extinguisher  | Powder ABE     | Capacity (kg)  | 9.0    |
            | 10 | Fire Hose Reel     | General        | Length (m)     | 12.0   |
            ... CONTINUED
```

Currently it is possible to insert entries such as

```
            | 11 | Fire Hose Reel     | Powder ABE     | Dimensions     | 1200 x 1200 |
```

into the FIRE_OPTIONS table. This behaviour is very undesirable as this entry does not
conform to the declared (allowable) combinations specified in the other tables.

I would like to understand how I can implement suitable constraints on the FIRE_OPTIONS table so that an error is generated whenever a specified entry is not consistent with the other three tables.

I have tried using the "Database Tools"-"Relationships" feature however I have not been able to "Enforce Referential Integrity" between TBL_4 with TBL_1, TBL_2 and TBL_3 concurrently.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this issue.

** Edit

I was able to solve this problem through amending the Primary Key definitions. This is detailed below:

```
TBL_1 : FIRE_CLASSIFICATION
        PK: PK (Auto Increment)

TBL_2 : FIRE_TYPE
        PK: PK (Auto Increment) & FK_CLASS

TBL_3 : FIRE_SPECIFIC
        PK: PK (Auto Increment) & FK_CLASS

TBL_4 : FIRE_OPTIONS
        PK: PK (Auto Increment)
```

I then defined the following relationships within the "Database Tools"-"Relationships" feature:

```
[ERI]    FIRE_CLASSIFICATION.PK (1)  ->  FIRE_TYPE.FK_CLASS (MANY)
[ERI]    FIRE_CLASSIFICATION.PK (1)  ->  FIRE_SPECIFIC.FK_CLASS (MANY)
[ERI] {  FIRE_CLASSIFICATION.PK (1)  ->  FIRE_OPTIONS.FK_CLASS (MANY)
         FIRE_TYPE.PK (1)            ->  FIRE_OPTIONS.FK_TYPE (MANY)
         FIRE_TYPE.FK_CLASS (1)      ->  FIRE_OPTIONS.FK_CLASS (MANY)
         FIRE_SPECIFIC.PK (1)        ->  FIRE_OPTIONS.FK_SPECIFIC (MANY)
         FIRE_SPECIFIC.FK_CLASS (1)  ->  FIRE_OPTIONS.FK_CLASS (MANY)    }

ERI : "Enforce Referential Integrity" Option Selected
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, since there is a one to one relationship between the FIRE_CLASSIFICATION and FIRE_SPECIFIC tables, you could add the SPECIFIC column to the FIRE_CLASSIFICATION table.
This might not work if things became more complex though.